# Double slit experiment: what happens when an electron or photon hits the wall? Does it goes through the slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

What happens when an electron or a photon hits the wall between the two slits or to the left or right of one of them? Does it bounces back or does a goes through (both slits)?

When a photon goes through both slits, it seems to me that it is everywhere, not only before the slits. So when it hits the wall, it is also before the two slits. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the wavefunction that hit the wall do not go through. Only the parts of the wavefunction in front of the slit can pass through. Whether the particle is reflected or absorbed is determined by what the wall and the particle actually are. The difference doesn't really matter anyway, because unless you add more reflectors to redirect reflected particles back to the slits, they will eventually hit an absorber. When part of the wavefunction hits an absorber, that counts as a quantum measurement: either the particle hits the absorber (changing its state e.g. by heating) and the rest of the wavefunction disappears in collapse, or it doesn't hit and the part of the wavefunction entering the absorber collapses away and leaves the rest. (This is the Copenhagen interpretation, at least.) In the reflecting case, if the reflected wavefunction has no chance of making it back to the slits, you can move the collapse up to the time of reflection. So for both a reflecting or absorbing wall, when the wavefunction of the particle reaches it and the slits, the particle will either collapse into having hit the wall, or will collapse into the restriction of the wavefunction outside the wall (i.e. collapse into having a wavefunction inside both slits).

To the experiment this doesn't conceptually matter because we only detect particles if they hit the detector which is behind the wall. The part of the wavefunction that hits the wall matters only in that it makes the experiment inefficient: each particle can either go through the slits and end up on the screen and contribute to the interference pattern... or it can hit the wall and get lost. Considering that a lot/most of the area of the input beam falls on the wall as opposed to the slits, this means if you want a certain amount of particles at the detector to get a good signal, you will need to send a lot more particles than that into the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The wave function gives the probability of finding a particle on the 'wall' or on the slits. The standard double slit experiment assumes (perpendicular) illumination with a plane wave so this probability is uniform. Whether particles get absorbed or reflected by the slit system is irrelevant to the interference on the screen.